# Code protection (firmware security) in PI PICO RP2040?

Tags: microcontroller, protection, code, rp2040

What are the available code protection (firmware security) options for off chip flash in PI PICO RP2040 for industrial IP critical designs?

Comment: Do you mean code protection in the off-chip Flash?

Comment: Yes... I want to protect my design from competitors

Comment: This board doesn't seem to be a good alternative. You may find this discussion very informative: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=300338

Answer (score 5):

There are none; that MCU can execute code either from RAM or directly from flash.

Since you'd need to encrypt the flash, all you could do is implement a decryptor in software that decrypts the flash into RAM before executing that code.

**That means you cannot do this**; the RP2040 has no internal memory for the secret key to decrypt, so you need to have that key outside of the MCU, unencrypted. Which negates the whole thing.

Also, the RP2040 can't be locked down against debuggers, so you can always read the RAM - so you *can*t have anything secret in this.

In other words: if code secrecy is what you need, this is the worst possible choice. *Any* other modern microcontroller at least brings internal flash and can disable debugging. *Some* actually bring physically unextractable memory.

The RP2040 is about as "boring" as microcontrollers get: a cortex-M0 core (so: the most common 32 bit processor core on earth, probably!), clocked unusually high, but with very little periphery to make that high-clock-speed, low-things-per-clock worthwhile. I'm sure you'll find another cortex-M that does the thing you need the RP2040 for but actually brings the capabilities you need. Note that really security-oriented MCUs come at a premium, usually. Many of them have been cracked before.

The question is, really, whether you're not barking up the wrong tree: the RP2040, with its lack of on-chip nonvolatile memory and its relatively low-cost and low-guarantees specifications, don't really scream "I should be doing industrial critical designs based on this". Very much in the original spirit of the RPi Foundation, it's something for tinkerers. You might simply be looking at the wrong market segment here! (Or overestimating the attractiveness of copying the firmware of any product you're likely to design.)

Comment: The Teensy 4.0 uses external flash and has an option to protect it using encryption. It's a roughly equivalent controller, but is about 10 X more expensive...

Comment: Comparing the teensy to the rp2040 is like comparing a car to a car engine. It's a microcontroller experimenter board, the rp2040 is just a microcontroller.